# Pulling all documents from collection with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

**EDIT:** my mistake was never actually using an `$http.get` call on `/spells`, so the`router.get` never occured.

In my `app.js`, I have the lines...

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('...');
require('./models/spells');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
```

`spells.js` defines a `SpellSchema`...

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var SpellSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  level: String,
  school: String,
  ritual: String,
  classes: [String],
  castingTime: String,
  range: String,
  components: [String],
  duration: String,
  description: [String],
  page: String
}, {});

mongoose.model('spell', SpellSchema);
```

And then in `index.js` I do...

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var test = mongoose.model('spell');
router.get('/spells', function(req, res, next) {
  test.find({}, function(err, data) {
    console.log(err, data, data.length);
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    res.json(data);
  });
});
```

But the `console.log` prints nothing. If at the end of `spells.js` I have...

```
var test = mongoose.model('spell', SpellSchema);
test.find({}, function(err, data) {
    console.log(err, data, data.length);
}
```

... all of the spell documents are printed to the console.

I'm a little confused as to why this is happening? As far as I'm aware it should print the spells.

Comment: did you check on terminal spell collection have data ?

Comment: @MuhammadAli Yes, it definitely has data.

Comment: would you please check the collection name is spell or spells?

Comment: @MuhammadAli The collection name is `spells`, and as far as I'm aware, calling `mongoose.model()` uses the plural version of `spell` for the collection name.

Answer (score 0):

try with this one

```
data = JSON.stringify(data);
data = JSON.parse(data);
res.json(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this?

```
var SpellModel = require('./shell');
SpellModel.find({}, console.log);
```

I don't think that you should call the mongoose.model, since that mongo db connection might not be available yet.

Comment: all collections are printed to console .. already written above